# How can I seperate functions which are basically the same but use different states? Vue2/Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Ive got a problem since i realized that I break the DRY(Dont repeat yourself) rule. So basically I have 2 modules(movies, cinemas) and few methods in them which look the same but use their module' state.
Example: Movies has 'movies' state. Cinemas has 'cinemas' state.

```
      //cinemas.ts
    @Mutation
  deleteCinemaFromStore(id: string): void {
    const cinemaIndex = this.cinemas.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (cinemaIndex >= 0) {
      const cinemasCopy = this.cinemas.map((obj) => {
        return { ...obj };
      });
      cinemasCopy.splice(cinemaIndex, 1);
      this.cinemas = cinemasCopy;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Provided id doesn't exist");
    }
  }

   //movies.ts
@Mutation
  deleteMovieFromStore(id: string): void {
    const movieIndex = this.movies.findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (movieIndex >= 0) {
      const moviesCopy = this.movies.map((obj) => {
        return { ...obj };
      });
      moviesCopy.splice(movieIndex, 1);
      this.movies = moviesCopy;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Provided id doesn't exist");
    }
  }
```

My struggle is: How can I seperate these methods into utils.ts if they have reference to 2 different states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define another function that take the id, state and store context (this) as parameters :

```
function delete(id:string,itemsName:string,self:any){

 const itemIndex= self[itemsName].findIndex((item) => item.id === id);
    if (itemIndex>= 0) {
      const itemsCopy = self[itemsName].map((obj) => {
        return { ...obj };
      });
     itemsCopy.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      self[itemsName] = itemsCopy;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Provided id doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

then use it like :

```
     //cities.ts
    @Mutation
  deleteCityFromStore(id: string): void {
   delete(id,'cities',this)
  }

  //countries.ts
@Mutation
  deleteCountryFromStore(id: string): void {
    delete(id,'countries',this)
}
```

Comment: Thats working, thank you a lot!! Would you have any docs to read to expand my knowledge about it? I couldn't find any to be honest

Comment: this is a js stuff and it's one of the good practices that you could find them on some forums like dev.to or you learn them by experience